# Google Cloud SQL api export csv: custom delimiter, handle 'N' value and set utf8mb64

Tags: java, google-cloud-sql

I can export csv file from sql database by calling the api.

Here are what I want:

1. Set the delimiter to a pipe '|'
2. Get empty string '' for NULL value
3. Set character set to 'utf8mb64'

But I got:

1. Delimiter ',' (by default)
2. 'N' for NULL value from the table

My request body:

```
{
 "exportContext":
   {
      "fileType": "CSV",
      "uri": "gs://test-bucket-store/hello/hello.csv",
      "databases": ["hello"],
      "csvExportOptions":
       {
           "selectQuery":"SELECT * FROM tbl_hello"
       }
   }
}
```

I tried with this one but it doesn't work:

```
{
 "exportContext":
   {
      "fileType": "CSV",
      "uri": "gs://test-bucket-store/hello/hello.csv",
      "databases": ["hello"],
      "csvExportOptions":
       {
           "selectQuery":"SELECT * FROM tbl_hello",
           "fieldDelimiters": "|",
           "encoding": "utf8mb64"
       }
   }
}
```

I have no idea how to set these options in **Java**. And I cannot see any solution from Google Cloud's Document. Please give me a suggestion.

Google Cloud's Document: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/export

Comment: I think this would be a good point to discuss in the [Cloud SQL Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-discuss). The documentation shows `csvExportOptions` as as property within `ExportContext` but doesn't go further into detail on what are the exact options you can set. I would invite you to raise this as a point of discussion within that Group.

Comment: @JKleinne That's great! please invite me to that group.

Comment: You can simply click the `Join group to post` button and a moderator will let you in.